# Get SharePoint List columns

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, custom-fields

I am programing a custom field type where the user can type a site URL, select a site and select a column of the selected list.

**How do I get the columns of the list?**

What I have tried now seams to work but I am receiving all too much data. Here is how i get the columns:

```
private void getColumnsOfSelectedList()
{
    DdlLookupFieldDataList.Items.Clear();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LabelLookupFieldTargetURLText.Text))
    {
        //Get the lists of the site from the Site URL
        site = new SPSite(LabelLookupFieldTargetURLText.Text);
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

        foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
        {
            if (list.Title == DdlLookupFieldTargetList.SelectedItem.Text)
                foreach (var item in list.Fields)
                    DdlLookupFieldDataList.Items.Add(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

BR

Comment: Yes I am getting many more colums than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `SPField.Title` to display the field. Depending on the audience it makes sense to display the `SPField.InternalName` as well. The member `SPField.AuthoringInfo` returns more information on the field. This is useful for fields with the same title.

```
Title
Title (linked to item with edit menu)
Title (linked to item)
```

Where the text in the brackets comes from the authoring info field.

**Update:**

The `list.Fields` returns a `SPFieldCollection` which contains `SPField` objects.

```
foreach (SPField /* <-- */  field in list.Fields)
{
  DdlLookupFieldDataList.Items.Add(new ListItem(
    String.Format("{0} {1}", field.Title, field.AuthoringInfo), 
    field.InternalName));
}
```

Comment: hmm I guess you miss understood me. I asked if you counld tell´me how to put it into my example. Into the code in the question?